# GraphQL: Integer too long? (AWS Amplify/GraphQL Transform)

Tags: graphql, aws-amplify

I use GraphQL Transform as part of AWS Amplify. Now I want to create the following mutation. However, it seems the `to` integer is too long. Reading the documentation it should be able to be much longer. Do you know why I always receive the error: `Validation error of type WrongType: argument 'input.to' with value 'IntValue{value=49160381234}' is not a valid 'Int' @ 'createNumber`

```
mutation createNumber {
  createNumber(input: {
    username: "mymail@gmail.com"
    to: 49160381234
  }) {
    username
    to
  }
}
```

Here my schema:

```
type Message
  @model
  @auth(rules: [{ allow: owner }])
  @key(fields: ["to", "from"]) # `to` as primary index and `from` as sort key.
  @key(
    name: "byToByTimestamp"
    fields: ["to", "timestamp"]
    queryField: "messagesByToByTimestamp"
  ) {
  to: Int!
  from: String!
  medium: String!
  messageBody: String!
  timestamp: Int!
}

type Number
  @model
  @key(fields: ["to"]) # Each number can only exist once.
  @key(
    name: "byUserByTo"
    fields: ["username", "to"]
    queryField: "numberByUserByTo"
  ) {
  username: String!
  to: Int!
  messages: [Message] @connection(keyName: "byToByTimestamp", fields: ["to"])
}

type User @model @key(fields: ["username"]) {
  username: String!
  numbers: [Number] @connection(keyName: "byUserByTo", fields: ["username"])
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [the spec](https://graphql.github.io/graphql-spec/June2018/#sec-Int):

> The Int scalar type represents a signed 32‐bit numeric non‐fractional value. Response formats that support a 32‐bit integer or a number type should use that type to represent this scalar... If the integer internal value represents a value less than -2^31 or greater than or equal to 2^31, a field error should be raised.

Since an Int has to be a 32-bit value, its value cannot be greater than 2147483647. For fields that may have values higher than that, the spec suggests:

> Numeric integer values larger than 32‐bit should either use String or a custom‐defined Scalar type, as not all platforms and transports support encoding integer numbers larger than 32‐bit.

Comment: Ah interesting, that explains why I could enter longer integers in DynamoDB directly, but not via GraphQL mutation. Thank you Daniel!